# Trace norm of adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

For a positive operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$, the trace of $A$ is defined by

$$Tr (A)=\sum_i\langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$$

where $\{e_i\}$ is any orthonormal basis of $H$.

For a general bounded operator $A$ on $H$, $A$ is said to be of **trace class** if the trace of $|A|:=\sqrt{A^*A}$ is finite. We can also define the **trace norm** of a trace class oeprator to be $||A||_1:=Tr(|A|)$.

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that $||A^*||_1 = ||A||_1$. I am stuck because there seems to be no easy way to relate the operators $|A|$ and $|A^*|$. Any help will be appreciated.

It is so much easier to prove that the Frobenius norm $||A^*||_2 = ||A||_2$. The inner product form plus the absolute value makes the trace norm quite nasty!

Comment: I think your definition might be a bit inaccurate; you have to require that $\sum_i \langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$ converges for all orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$, and only then can you say the trace is well-defined. Alternatively you could require that $A$ be compact, but the condition I listed above would also imply that $A$ is compact.

Comment: The first definition is for positive operators. You can show that for positive operators, the sum is independent of the choice of orthonormal basis (e.g. consider its squareroot and prove that $\sum_i ||A^{1/2} e_i||^2$ is independent of choice of orthonormal basis, which is proven on some other questions on this site.)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, being trace class implies that $A$ is compact. Then $|A|$ is compact, so by the spectral theorem $|A|$ has a decreasing sequence of positive eigenvalues $s_n(A)$ tending to $0$. If we let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $|A|$, then $|A| = \sum_i s_i(A) e_i\otimes e_i^\ast$  and also
$$\|A\|_1 = \sum_i \langle|A|e_i,e_i\rangle = \sum_i s_n(A)$$
Moreover by the polar decomposition we can write
$$A = U|A|$$
where $U$ is a partial isometry. If we let $f_n = Ue_n$ then we have
$$A = \sum_is_n(A)f_i \otimes e_i^\ast$$

The following is a lemma 1.4 from Ken Davidson's book "Nest Algebras" (which is free to download on his website).

Claim: Fix $n \ge 1$. Then
$$s_n(A)= \inf\{\|A - F\|: rank F \le n-1\}$$

Proof: Let $F_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} s_k f_k \otimes e_k^\ast$ and then $A - F_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty s_k f_k \otimes e_k^\ast$. Thus
$s_n(A)  = \|A - F_n\|$ and the $\ge$ inequality follows.
Conversely if $rank F \le n-1$ then choose a unit vector $x \in ker F \cap span \{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ and then
$$\|A - F\| \ge \|(A - F)x\| = \|Ax\| 
    = \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n s_k(A)(x, e_k)f_k\right\| 
     \ge s_n(A) \sum_{k=1}^n |(x,e_k)|^2 
      = s_n(A)$$
Which proves the claim.

Finally, for any finite rank $F$ we have that $dim(Range(F)) = dim(Range(F^\ast))$ and
$$\|A - F\| = \|(A-  F)^\ast\| = \|A^\ast - F^\ast\|$$
And hence it follows that
$$s_n(A) = \inf\{\|A - F\|: rank F \le n-1\}=\inf\{\|A^\ast - F^\ast\|: rank F \le n-1\} = s_n(A^\ast)$$
And so
$$\|A\|_1 = \sum_i s_i(A) = \sum_i s_i(A^\ast) = \|A^\ast\|_1$$